# How to stop my puppy from eating his stool?

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, toilet-training

I have a 4 months old puppy who is healthy and playful. For the past one week he started eating his own stool.

There is a place reserved for his #1 and #2, and he does those activities there only. I tried to constantly monitor him but I miss always. He is too sneaky.

I googled and I saw some products for this but I don't know whether they will work or good for his health.

Is there any suggestion to stop him from eating stool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: puppies and dogs that eat their own and other dog's stools are often created in environments where there is overcrowding and the puppies need to struggle to get food. The weakest puppy will often not get food and so will resort to eating stools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your dog is enjoying his home-made snack! Here's a few tips we recommend at the hospital:

1. Pick up stool as soon as it comes out, need to be a bit more watchful.
2. [For-Bid](http://www.for-bid.com/) - all the hospitals I've worked at carry this product, you'll need to use it for a week or 2 so the dog learns to avoid stools all together.
3. Canned pineapple - You only need a small amount in comparison to the size of the dog to change the taste of the stool so they don't eat it. Too much can cause GI upset.

   - Small dog (0-10kg) - 1/8th of a cup per meal
   - Medium dog (11-30kg) - 1/4 of a cup per meal
   - Large dog (>30kg) - 1/4 to 1/2 of a cup per meal

These tricks may stop working once you stop using them but don't worry! It is gross but not harmful for the dog to eat his poo and also **NOT** an indicator that he's ill or in poor health, he just genuinely enjoys eating it. I know some dogs who only eat their poo in the winter as it's frozen (poopsicles).

He may grow out of it as he ages, though not always the case. Some dogs will eat their stools because they are hungry as well, growing dogs need to eat more while some breeds are [genetically predisposed to ALWAYS be hungry](http://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/why-labradors-wont-stop-eating/).

Answer (score 0):

When my dog was a puppy she not only ate her own stool, but other dog stools as well. My vet gave me some medication to stop this, and she stopped within 2 weeks. There are some non-prescription products that you can use as well to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My dog Lilly has been doing this since she was a puppy (Now she is two). She is the dominate female in our household of four dogs total and will only eat the other female dogs stool. Over time we have tried supplements to deter her eating stool, natural sources such as pineapple, and vitamins to supplement her diet to make sure she is getting enough (Read that vitamin B deficiency leads to dogs eating stool). After all these things nothing seemed to work so we brought her too two different Vets, both said it is natural for her as the dominate breed in the house and that the only real solution is to clean up the stool as soon as it is made or let the dogs out separately. This is so far the only solution that has worked for me and my wife. I wanted to add this too the list as our Lilly has been an outlier on most remedies that work on other dogs.